# Dual Monitors no longer work after physically installing harddrives (Ubuntu 20.04) [Solved]

Tags: boot, multiple-monitors, xorg, display, display-resolution

I'm on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS MATE, using a Radeon RX6800 Gaming OC 16 GB and 2 IIyama 4K Monitors both attached via Display port. Both Monitors worked on 1920x2160 Resolution for a total 3840x2160 Desktop.

This worked without problems until recently: I shut the computer down, installed two hard drives from my old computer (ext4 Filesystems) and turned it on again. I did nothing else!!!

Now my screen/resolution/desktop is all screwed up: "Displays" shows just one monitor (Unknown) with the total 3840x2160 resolution with a 0Hz refresh rate (rotation normal). Trying to change the selected resolution of 3840x2160 results in distorted colors being shown (probably because it's not 3840 but really 1016x2160 on the one monitor that turns on, see xrandr below).

The file ".config/monitors.xml" is not used. Editing it had no effect, neither had deleting it. Presently there is no monitors.xml on the system.

I have also tried to boot to recovery mode to execute "Xorg -configure", which I did - but again to no effect.

There is no xorg.conf to find anywhere as well.

output of xrandr:
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 800 x 600, current 3840 x 2160, maximum 3840 x 2160
default connected primary 3840x2160+0+0 0mm x 0mm
3840x2160      0.00*
1600x1200      0.00
1400x1050      0.00
1280x1024      0.00
1280x960       0.00
1280x720       0.00
1024x768       0.00
800x600        0.00

and of xrandr --listmonitors:
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Monitors: 1
0: +*default 3840/1016x2160/571+0+0  default

The 1016x2160 seems to be the actual resolution the one monitor is showing.

It seems monitor settings are not saved but are detected each time at startup - wrongly detected. But this is only a guess.

The also installed Windows system worked as it did before with both monitors and total 3840x2160 resolution, so it shouldn't be a hardware problem.

What I really don't get is why installing new hard drives can have such an effect..

Thank you!!
RevJ

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this by reinstalling the amdgpu packages. Not that it should have happened in the first place.

Sidenote: physically disconnecting on monitor resulted in a new monitors.xml being created.

Thank you all!